# Small Caps and Digits

Tags: css

I'm facing a weird problem with small-caps and digits. While my text, when I tell him via

```
p {
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

is using small-caps, digits stay big. Anyone know that problem and a workaround. Or do I have to wrap digits in a span and scale them down by hand? I'm using a webfont, which is showing small-caps in Photoshop. So the font-family provides small-caps for digits.

Comment: AFAIK, digits will always be treated as uppercase by `small-caps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because digits have no case. Digits are neither upper nor lower case, so they cannot be converted like that.

A workaround is to instead make your `font-size` smaller and force your text to be upper case with the `text-transform` property:

```css
p {
    font-size: smaller;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

The only problem with this is that it will also affect letters which are already upper case.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/etuyekzb/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use parts of your solution. I'll wrap my digits into spans and scale them down. small-caps just looks different than smaller uppercase letters.